# How to set custom page urls in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, post, permalinks

Actually, I am using advance custom field plugin and I have made a repeater with three fields language, release and download (file type).

So now I have made a custom template for every post and retrieved repeater fields on it so I want that when user will click on download button then it will redirect on another page with a custom URL with post name and language both.

I need post name and language into that link then on final page

I will give the download option. Below are pages link of the post

https://subtitlesrt.com/movie-imdb/fifty-shades-freed-2018-arabic-subtitles-download-srt-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%81%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85/

I have also set download page on custom page.

Let me know the right solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i were you i would follow these steps.

1. Create a new page with name of Custom download maybe
2. create a custom template for that page
3. in your posts when you show repeater values, use the values like a form with GET method (maybe input types can be hidden for aesthetic) and submit the form to this new page.
4. In this page you can get the repeater field values with form and do whatever you want.

NOTE: i suggested GET method because you said "... it will redirect on other page with a custom url .." GET method show values in url and you can index them.

Comment: OK I will get value on download page by this method but if there are five rows with repeater values and in these values there is a field 'Langauge' and also there a download button with every row. So I want that when user will click on download button then in site url there should be post name and language too because every row should have different language and url will be according to language but post name will be same. let me know about the solution

Comment: You can add whatever you want in url as form value Ex: <input type="text" name="postname" value="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"> ....... Or you can add an input for determining wich row is it like Ex: <input type="text" name="row" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">  (key is array key which return in foreach);